# Clicking row in catalog product grid doesn't work

Tags: magento2, product-grid

I am facing very unusual error on clicking the row in catalog product grid. Normally, it should open the product edit page. But now it does nothing, except the error that I am getting in console.
[image]

However, the edit link under action column is working.
So, if anyone can solve this, Please help!!

Comment: I had same issue with you. In my case, my custom module affect to open the product view. Please check your custom file!